# How to fix slow distinct query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Using Rails and Postgres.

I have 3 tables (let's call them "manufacturers", "helicopters" and "boats").
Manufacturer model is associated with has_many to Helicopter (through "manufacturer_helicopters" table and model) and with has_many to Boats (through "manufacturer_boats" table and model).

On the show page, I should render unique Manufacturers which either are connected to Helicopter (which has one of "helicopter_ids") or are connected to Boat (which has one of "boat_ids").

Moreover "helicopter" association has a higher priority, so we should filter only those manufacturers which either have "helicopter" with given helicopter_id or have no "helicopter" at all.

That's the query I've come up with, but it's really slow - takes few seconds to query (tables have almost 1mil records each)

```
result = Manufacturer.distinct(:id)
                     .left_outer_joins(:manufacturer_helicopters, :manufacturer_boats)
                     .where('helicopter_id IN (?) OR boat_id IN (?)', helicopter_ids, boat_ids)
result.where('manufacturer_helicopters.helicopter_id = ? OR manufacturer_helicopters.helicopter_id IS NULL', helicopter_id)
```

I'd really appreciate any suggestions how to improve the performance.

EDIT
Here's explain

```
 Unique  (cost=104750.30..115799.60 rows=184155 width=384)
   ->  Sort  (cost=104750.30..105210.69 rows=184155 width=384)
         Sort Key: manufacturer.id, manufacturer.full_name, manufacturer.serial_number, manufacturer.contact_email, manufacturer.pending, manufacturer.created_at, manufacturer.updated_at, manufacturer.in_production, manufacturer.in_planning, manufacturer.web_url, manufacturer.mobile_url, manufacturer.country, manufacturer.city, manufacturer.zip_code, manufacturer.logo, manufacturer.street, manufacturer.address, manufacturer.last_manufactured_at, manufacturer.archived, manufacturer.external_manufacturer_id, manufacturer.external_serial_number, manufacturer.distributor_id, manufacturer.visible
         ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1.35..24441.43 rows=184155 width=384)
               Merge Cond: (manufacturer.id = manufacturer_helicopter.helicopter_id)
               Filter: ((manufacturer_helicopter.helicopter_id = 4) OR (manufacturer_boat.boat_id = 1))
               ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1.06..19442.76 rows=260211 width=388)
                     Merge Cond: (manufacturer.id = manufacturer_boat.boat_id)
                     ->  Index Scan using manufacturer_pkey on manufacturers  (cost=0.42..11437.12 rows=260211 width=384)
                     ->  Index Scan using manufacturer_on_boat_id_boat on manufacturer_boat  (cost=0.42..5352.52 rows=160207 width=8)
               ->  Index Scan using index_manufacturer_helicopter_on_helicopter_id on manufacturer_helicopter  (cost=0.29..3343.37 rows=100005 width=8)
```

Comment: I would start with running [`explain`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain) on your query to see where bottleneck is. Right btree index might solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Is manufacturer.id indexed?  What is your manufacturer_pk?

Comment: Yes, manufacturer.id is indexed. It's the default primary key.

Comment: You have a huge sort key, your sort cost is the most expensive step. Any way to eliminate some of those sort fields?  Sorting on indexed fields is faster than unindexed fields.

Also, you may be getting slowed down by the IS NULL filter - I've seen that bypass indexes altogether.

Comment: How could I eliminate it?

Comment: If you mean by deleting the columns, then no, it can't be done.

Comment: not deleting the actual columns, just remove them from the sort statement.

Comment: @Roy I think postgres is adding that sort statement to support the DISTINCT.

Comment: Yep, Jeremy's right. I've removed distinct to try it and sort statement's gone.